# how to calculate request time without await

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

```
public Task<HealthCheckResult> CheckHealthAsync(HealthCheckContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            try
            {
                var sw = new Stopwatch();
                using var client = new HttpClient();

                var data = new StringContent(_json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                sw.Start();
                var result = client.PostAsync(_url, data);
                var respone = result.Result;
                sw.Stop();
                if (respone.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    //compare with request time
                    if(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < _threshold)
                    {
                        return Task.FromResult(HealthCheckResult.Healthy());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return Task.FromResult(HealthCheckResult.Degraded());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return Task.FromResult(HealthCheckResult.Unhealthy());
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return Task.FromResult(HealthCheckResult.Unhealthy());
            }
        }
```

this is how I calculate request time in my method. Is this correct? I've seen people use await in other answers, but I'm writing this in `Task<HealthCheckResult> CheckHealthAsync`and it says I need async method, but it already is.

Comment: Can you add some more code to make your question clearer. Why can't you use `await`?

Comment: Did you test this code? I'm surprised that this doesn't deadlock. Also, this won't even compile as written.

Comment: Added full method. I didn't make this method async because then my return type is wrong. Also doesn't the built-in name CheckHealthAsync suggests it's already async ? I need to return Task.FromResult. This is for .net core health checks

Comment: "it says I need async method, but it already is" - no it's not. You don't have the "async" contextual keyword in the declaration. To make it async, the method would be `public async Task<HealthCheckResult> CheckHealthAsync(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the `await` keyword, you must denote the method as well with the `async` keyword in its signature.

So your method becomes: `public async Task<HealthCheckResult> CheckHealthAsync`

And in your code, you need to await the `PostAsync` call, without blocking on the `.Result`:

```cs
sw.Start();
var response = await client.PostAsync(_url, data);
sw.Stop();
```

EDIT:

After the edit in your question, I see that you use `Task.FromResult(sth)`.

If you mark the method as `async`, you can (and must in order to compile) remove all of the `Task.FromResult` and just return `HealthCheckResult.Healthy()` instead.

Comment: oh yes, that was my problem with the return type. I didn't want to change it, since it was in documentation. I thought it might screw up the health checks somehow. But I left HealthCheckResult.Healthy() like you say :) thank you